# Delphi accessing data from json object

Tags: json, delphi

I need to write some code to retrieve data from a JSON string that my application will receive from a web site.

This is the JSON string.

```json
{
  "client" :
     {
      "Name" : "john doe",
      "Phone" : 12345678,
      "Address": "5th av",
     },
  "order" : [
     {
      "Code" : 101,
      "Quantity" : 1,
      "Cost": 10.50,
      "Coment" : ""
     },
     {
      "Code" : 102,
      "Quantity" : 3,
      "Cost": 8.50,
      "Coment" : ""
     },
     {
      "Code" : 103,
      "Quantity" : 1,
      "Cost": 21.50,
      "Coment" : ""
     }
  ]
}
```

I am getting very confused about how to read pairs and arrays. I've tried lots of code posted here and other forums, but I still cannot get it done.

Can anyone give me some hints to get it done? I am using XE5 and JSON units.

Comment: There are tons of Delphi JSON examples floating around. Please show the actual code that you have already tried that is not doing what you need. We are not here to write the entire code for you, we are here to help you work with code you write yourself.

Comment: you have mistake in your JSON string. Extra comma after `"Address": "5th av"`

Answer (score 5):

I'm not going to write the actual code for you, but I am going to give you a hint.

Here is the structure of the JSON you have shown:

```
object
|
|_ client (object)
|  |_ Name (string)
|  |_ Phone (string)
|  |_ Address (string)
|
|_ order (array)
  |_ [0] (object)
  |  |_ Code (number)
  |  |_ Quantity (number)
  |  |_ Code (number)
  |  |_ Coment (string)
  |
  |_ [1] (object)
  |  |_ Code (number)
  |  |_ Quantity (number)
  |  |_ Code (number)
  |  |_ Coment (string)
  |
  |_ [2] (object)
     |_ Code (number)
     |_ Quantity (number)
     |_ Code (number)
     |_ Coment (string)
```

You can map that 1-to-1 to Delphi's native JSON classes in the [`Data.DBXJSON`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSON) unit (they were moved to the [`System.JSON`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON) unit in XE6).

1. Start by passing the JSON string to [`TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue), which returns a [`TJSONValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONValue). Type-cast that to a [`TJSONObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONObject).
2. Use its [`Values`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONObject.Values) property to access the `client` and `order` values.  Type-cast them to `TJSONObject` and [`TJSONArray`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONArray), respectively.
3. For the `client` object, use its `Values` property to access the `Name`, `Phone`, and `Address` values. You can call their [`Value()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONAncestor.Value) method to get their string values.
4. for the `order` array, use its [`Count`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONArray.Count) and [`Items`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONArray.Items) properties, or its [`GetEnumerator`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONArray.GetEnumerator) method (indirectly in a [`for..in` loop](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Iteration_Over_Containers_Using_For_statements), to iterate through the array items.  Type-cast each one to a `TJSONObject` to access its `Values` property.  For the number values, type-cast them to [`TJSONNumber`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONNumber) to access their [`AsInt`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONNumber.AsInt), [`AsInt64`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONNumber.AsInt64), and [`AsDouble`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONNumber.AsDouble) properties as needed.

See Embarcadero's [JSON documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/JSON) for more information.

Comment: Many thanks Remy, I did not want the code, just want to someone to clarify the structure as you did . I have now more to work with.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to work with json i advise you to work with [alcinoe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/alcinoe/). but use the SVN version it's the most accurate: svn checkout svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/alcinoe/code/ alcinoe-code

don't use the delphi json object (dbxjson), it's terribly slow (their is a demo in the alcinoe that compare aljsonDoc / SuperObject / dbxjon you will see by yourself the disaster with dbxjson

exemple of how to use

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: { first: "John", last: "Backus" },
  birth: new Date('1999-10-21T21:04:54.234Z'),
  contribs: [ "Fortran", "ALGOL", "Backus-Naur Form", "FP" ],
  awards: [
            { award: "National Medal of Science",
              year: 1975,
              by: "National Science Foundation" },
            { award: "Turing Award",
              year: 1977,
              by: "ACM" }
          ],
  spouse: "",
  address: {},
  phones: []
}
```

to access the document node :

```
MyJsonDoc.loadFromJson(AJsonStr, False);
MyJsonDoc.childnodes['_id'].int32;
MyJsonDoc.childnodes['name'].childnodes['first'].text;
MyJsonDoc.childnodes['name'].childnodes['last'].text;
MyJsonDoc.childnodes['birth'].datetime;
for i := 0 to MyJsonDoc.childnodes['contribs'].ChildNodes.count - 1 do
  MyJsonDoc.childnodes['contribs'].childnodes[i].text;
for i := 0 to MyJsonDoc.childnodes['awards'].ChildNodes.count - 1 do begin
  MyJsonDoc.childnodes['awards'].childnodes[i].childnodes['award'].text;
  MyJsonDoc.childnodes['awards'].childnodes[i].childnodes['year'].text;
  MyJsonDoc.childnodes['awards'].childnodes[i].childnodes['by'].text;
end;
```

you can read the full doc of aljsondoc [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/alcinoe/wiki/ALJsonDocument/)

Comment: This is not a site for *I recommend my favorite open-source/freeware/shareware/commercial product* posts. If you want to endorse one of those, write a blog post doing so. You can't propose an *alternative* to *I've done nothing, so please write some code for me*.