# GET Value from restresponse Json

Tags: json, delphi, facebook-graph-api, delphi-10-seattle

Any way to retrieve `url` key from this JSON?

```json
{
  "data": {
    "is_silhouette": false,
    "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/13178742_10205047662871072_6233795154346712405_n.jpg?oh=194b0150c2325660390490779bf9b942&oe=57C22031&__gda__=1472746057_dc9b0557adc8408840fafb73ed325ef8"
  }
}
```

It is provided by [Facebook's Graph API](http://graph.facebook.com/10204985653320872/picture?type=large&redirect=false). I'm using a Rest Library in Delphi 10.0 Seattle to retrieve it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37887564/62576 will give you some suggestions regarding how to get started. We're not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start by reading Embarcadero's [JSON documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Json).  You can use the classes in the [`System.JSON`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON) unit, eg:

```
uses
  ..., System.JSON;

var
  json: string;
  obj, data: TJSONObject;
  url: string;
begin
  json := ...; // JSON data retrieved from REST server
  obj := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(json) as TJSONObject;
  try
    data := obj.Values['data'] as TJSONObject;
    url := data.Values['url'].Value;
  finally
    obj.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively, if you are using Embarcadero's [REST client library](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/REST_Client_Library), it can retrieve and pre-parse the JSON for you:

```
var
  obj, data: TJSONObject;
  url: string;
begin
  RESTRequest1.Execute;
  obj := RESTResponse1.JSONValue as TJSONObject;
  data := obj.Values['data'] as TJSONObject;
  url := data.Values['url'].Value;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, I did expressed myself wrong. I already had a code to do this, but it wasn't the way I wanted.

Comment: Thank you again, but
`obj.Free;`
Is causing a EInvalidPointer exception with message "Invalid Pointer Operation Exception", when closing application.